# Prevent Python module from being imported from a particular other module

Tags: python

I'm trying to prevent a module from being imported by a specific other module:

Z.py:

```
#if B is the module that is trying to import me: <- what goes here?
   #raise exception
print("Z")
```

A.py:

```
import Z
print("A")
```

B.py

```
import Z
print("B")
```

Expected output:

```
>> python A.py
>> "A" \n "Z"
>> python B.py
>> Exception: bla traceback etc...
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Then you can write in `B.py`: `from A import Z` and there goes the protection. Just out of curiosity: why would anyone want that?

Comment: @bereal Yea, that would be a shortcut, but then you break it very explicitly. My goal here is to have some runtime protection of package integrity. I want single module interface in my package and have clients of this package only use that, since there is module level caching going on in there.

Comment: This is a really weird thing to want. If you're the one writing `B`, just don't import `Z`. If it's someone else's module, why stop them? Do you really hate the developers of `B` and not want them to use your code? (You haven't asked for a way to stop imports from general categories of modules, only specific modules.)

Comment: Just stick an underscore in front of a module if you don't want external clients to use it. Actually stopping people from importing your module isn't possible.

Comment: "We're all consenting adults here".

Comment: "Errors should never pass silently"

Answer (score 0):

The `_Z.py` *convention* is useful here, but I am looking for a somewhat more robust fail save.

Found some solution that looks at the frames:

_Z.py ;)

```
import inspect, os

calling_path = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][0])[0]
calling_module_name = os.path.basename(calling_path).replace(".py","")
if not calling_module_name.startswith("A"):
    raise Exception("You cannot import me")

print("_Z")
```

However this string matching does not appeal to me so if someone has a more elegant solution; I am open to it.

Comment: Not gonna work, because module's code is executed only once. If `A` imported anywhere before `B` (or within `B` before `_Z`), then `_Z` will execute its check for `A`. `B` will try to import `_Z` and obtain the instance from the cache.

Comment: @bereal yes, you are right. Does not work, test only runs at first import. Guess the underscore is the only thing that will "work" here.